# Map the number of occurrence of elements in an array or stream

Tags: java

I would like to count how many of each element are there in an int array. I was thinking streaming the array into a `Map<Integer, Integer>` would be a good solution but there seems to be a problem with my `Supplier` argument.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

('dice' is my int array)

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = Stream.of(dice)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: can you try `Arrays.stream()`

Comment: " seems to be a problem with my Supplier argument"  - What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stream.of(dice)` creates a `Stream<int[]>` with a single element, not a `Stream<Integer>` with multiple elements.

Try:

```
Map<Integer,Long> map = Arrays.stream(dice)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()));
```

This way you'll create an `IntStream` from your array, and convert it to a `Stream<Integer>` with `boxed()`.

If for example, `dice` is defined as:

```
int[] dice = {1,2,3,4,3,2};
```

The output of `Map` will be:

```
{1=1, 2=2, 3=2, 4=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] dice = {1,2,2,3};
        Map<Integer, Long> map = Stream.of(dice)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

output:

```
{1=1, 2=2, 3=1}
```